# Can't fetch an item using xpath defined within my scraper

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I have tried to create two `xpaths` to get two items from some elements. However, first one is doing great but in case of second one: I can't get any idea. Any help on this will be appreciated.

```
<div class="mdif">
    <ul>
        <li><b>Genre:</b>Thriller</li> 
        <li><b>Quality:</b></li>1080p  
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried like this:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring   
content="""
<div class="mdif">
    <ul>
        <li><b>Genre:</b>Thriller</li> 
        <li><b>Quality:</b></li>1080p  
    </ul>
</div>
"""
root = fromstring(content)
for items in root.xpath("//div[@class='mdif']"):
    genre = items.xpath(".//li/text()")[0]
    # quality = items.xpath(".//li/text()")[0]
    print(genre,quality)
```

When I run the above script, it fetches the `genre` but in case of `quality` I get stuck. The output I wanna get is `1080p`.

Comment: You share two HTML source samples where quality values belongs to different parent nodes. Do you want a solution to match it in both situations?

Comment: Fixed the disparity, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this one to get quality value:

```
quality = items.xpath("./ul/text()[position()=last()]")[0]
```

This one might be applicable also:

```
quality = items.xpath(".//b[.='Quality:']/following::text()")[0]
```

Comment: It takes some time to accept your answer, sir. You are just invincible.